# Hide empty table (with whitespace) with css

Tags: html, css, html-table, laravel-blade

I'm using Blade to fill some tables with content but in some cases a table might end up empty when there is nothing to fill.

Here is part of the php / blade template:

```
<table class="table">
    @isset ($content->client)
    <tr>
        <td>
            Client:
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
            {{ $content->client }}
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endisset
    @isset ($content->published)
    <tr>
        <td>
            Published:
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
            {{ $content->published }}
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endisset
</table>
```

In case `$content->client` and `$content->published` are not set the result is something like:

```
<table class="table">
                            </table>
```

Is there a simple css way to remove the table entirely in these cases?
I'm familiar with the `:empty` selector but aparently that doesn't work if there are whitespaces in the tag :(

Comment: Perhaps if isset is true for any of your row conditions, use that to output opening and closing table tags?

Comment: @AndyClarke That's a solution, but unfortunately in the actual code there are a lot more properties that need to be checked. If there is no decent css solution I'll probably have to go that route.

Comment: @ArnovanOordt nope, sadly not possible at the moment, you'd have to use PHP or JS. But there is hope for the future: CSS4 will introduce :blank which does exactly this, but it's not supported in any browser as of today https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/b/blank/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:blank

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest not printing the table if either of the variables are empty.

```
<?php  
if( isset($content->client) || isset($content->published))
{
//    echo table
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `:blank`? It also selects whitespace while `:empty` does not.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:blank not supported by any browser